# How do I make custom comment tokens?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comments

[According to this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/10/create-custom-tokens-for-the-task-list-vstiptool0032.aspx), VS 2008 and 2010 had a feature called Comment Tokens. You can write `// TODO document this magic number here` and it will appear in your Comments section of the Task List. This part works for me.

However, that article says that you can even define your own tokens, by going to `Tools>Options>Environment>Task List` .

However, in my Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I don't have that option.

[image]

How do I make custom comment tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the "Show all settings" checkbox you see at the bottom left of the Options dialog. You now should be able to navigate to "Environment | Task List" to create your custom comments. Here is an additional link [How to: Create Custom Comment Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekwz6akh.aspx)